# Where can I find instructions on basic RNAseq data analysis?

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm trying to learn the basic workflow of RNAseq analysis: from aligning the reads to the genome, though evaluating read alignment quality, to measuring gene expression levels by counting reads.

I have found multiple sources that theoretically describe each step (I've looked at papers, websites, etc.), but I can't find practical instructions on how to do this: what programming packages to use, how to evaluate an alignment, etc.

Is there any online source that clearly explain how it's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread has some good resources:
http://biostars.org/p/45081/